# What can be with the battery?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery

My MacBook Pro (13-inch, mid 2010, El Capitan) periodically turns off. And this is happening completely randomly - sometimes it works fine for more than a day, and sometimes turns itself off 10 times in an hour, sometimes just turns off when you turn on the laptop. TG Pro App after each shutdown displays the message "Forced - Battery current outside limit". The number of charge cycles: 859. Maybe I should change the battery?

**UPD** I changed the battery but the problem remained.

[image: Coconuts Battery screenshot]

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of Coconuts Battery?

Comment: @Thomas added for new battery that I just install

Comment: You'll have to add some console output from just before it rebooted...

Answer (score 2):

**Yes** you have to change your battery.

The Apple technician will confirm you it is beyond dead, as a dead spring (a battery is just a chemical spring with a finite life).

Comment: So, I changed the battery but the problem remained.

Comment: Why did you install a 2.5 years old battery? The average time to live of modern batteries is under 3 years, and much shorter if you don't load them every 6 months.